# A conjecture about a particular polynomial with real roots $x$ s.t. $|x|\leq 1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, roots

I have the following conjecture:

Let $P(x)$ a polynomial

$$P(x)=a_nx^n+\dots+a_0,$$

such that

$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i=0;\quad \exists \;0<m<n\; s.t. a_m=-1; \quad 0\leq a_i\leq 1 \;\forall i\neq m$$

then all the real roots $x$ satisfy $|x|\leq 1$.

Now I know that is false (see below for a conterexample). Which hypothesis can I add to the statementet to be true?

Comment: I'm a little confused.  You say the sum of the $a_i$'s should be zero, so some of them will be negative?  Then you say that each $a_i$ is between 0 and 1?  Then you go on to require that one of them is -1?  These statements are inconsistent.  Maybe you want $0\leq |a_i|\leq 1$?

Comment: I guess that the modulus of $a_i$'a is between $0$ and $1$. So I correct the statement otherwise it is inconsistent as @DWiggles said above.

Comment: Take any polynomial $p(x)$ with real coefficients and $p(1)=0$ and divide it by minus the largest coefficient in absolute value - you get all the conditions satisfied and arbitrary roots except $1$.

Comment: I wrote the correct statement that I had in my mind.

Comment: Now I know that is false. Which hypothesis can I add to the statementet to be true?

Comment: With those hypothesis the statement is incosistent. Because if all $a_i$'s are positive, how is possible that there exists $m$ such that $a_m=-1$? You have to change your hypothesis first.

Comment: If $m=n$ then it is true. If $m=0$ then $|x|\ge 1$.

Comment: I correct the statement, now it is consistent.

Comment: But $m$ could not be equal to $0$ or to $m$

Answer (score 4):

You claim is false. Here a counterexample.

$$p(x)=\frac13x^2-x+\frac23$$

is a polynomial of that type, both roots are real, but one of them is $2$ which is clearly greater than one.